# Logstash "no such index error" when writting to Elasticsearch with X-Pack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have set a **version 5 ELK stack** (with X-Pack) and I use the following logstash conf file which seems to grok parse the access log correctly (as I see it in output):

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["/path/to/access_log"]
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
    mutate { replace => { "type" => "apache_access" } }
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }

  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"] 
    user => "elastic"
    password => "*****"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

However the elasticsearch output returns **404 ("no such index") error**  whatever I do except when I tried to create the index by hand using the following curl command:

```
curl -XPUT 'elastic:******@localhost:9200/logstash-2016.09.28
```

> [2016-11-02T17:30:09,535][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch]
>   Failed action. {:status=>404, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil,
>   :_index=>"logstash-2016.09.28", :_type=>"apache_access",
>   :_routing=>nil}, 2016-09-28T11:50:32.000Z mypchost 10.2.33.155 - -
>   [28/Sep/2016:14:50:32 +0300] "GET /MyApp/page HTTP/1.1" 302 -
>   "http://myhttpserver/MyApp/page?22" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
>   WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0" ],
>   :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-2016.09.28",
>   "_type"=>"apache_access", "_id"=>nil, "status"=>404,
>   "error"=>{"type"=>"index_not_found_exception", "reason"=>"no such
>   index", "resource.type"=>"index_expression",
>   "resource.id"=>"logstash-2016.09.28", "index_uuid"=>"*na*",
>   "index"=>"logstash-2016.09.28"}}}}

What could be the issue with not automatically creating the index?

**EDIT:**
Uninstalling the X-Pack from ES and re-running the logstash did the job, i.e. created an index.
Now I need to find out what is the problem with X-Pack.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, the issue was caused by the following line in **elasticsearch.yml** that I had added when installing the **X-Pack package** at ELK:

```
action.auto_create_index: .security,.monitoring*,.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history*
```

Comment: So comment out this line in configuration and then restart elasticsearch would work?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `logstash` output as this and try re-indexing it. I could see that you don't have the index parameter which you need the `logstash` file for it to create the index.

If you're indexing it using `logstash` you don't have to run a CURL command separately. This would create the index automatically.

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "yourindex"
    }

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Obviously it'll throw that error since the index has not been created. Check whether your index has been created once you run the `logstash` file using this CURL `curl 'yourhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'`. The above command would list out all the indices.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I still get: ` "_id"=>nil, "status"=>404, "error"=>{"type"=>"index_not_found_exception", "reason"=>"no such index", "resource.type"=>"i
ndex_expression", "resource.id"=>"myindex", "index_uuid"=>"_na_", "index"=>"myindex"}} `

Comment: Yes I am using the same logstash conf and unfortunatelly it does not create the index (based on indices list I get with curl). The hosts var should be an array, isn't it? Yes the ES is running but does not print any "create index" message.

Comment: @trikelef you're using the same logstash right, apart from the above change? Oops sorry I've updated the `hosts`, since you're using the localhost and the default port. You don't need the action and the host parameters. You're creating the index by running the logstash file right ?
You sure the elasticsearch is up and running ?

Comment: @trikelef I updated the output. Check running with only the index parameter. It should be fine. Check and let me know.  Did it work ?

Comment: Again I rerun the logstash using just index action and ES credentials but no luck.

Comment: @trikelef why don't you take off the credentials and run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127253/discussion-between-kulasangar-and-trikelef).